# model.findOne() returns null even though user exists in the mongodb in nodejs app

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to check if the user already exists in the database. I am sending the email id of the user from client side using javascript function to node js route. The route should find if user exists in the database or not. But all the results are coming as null.

```
/* this is the route*/
router.route('/checkUserInDatabase:email')
.get(async(req,res)=>{

const user = await User.findOne({ 'email': req.params.email });
console.log(user);
});

/* this is the client side function*/
function checkifEmailExists(x){
 $.get('/users/checkUserInDatabase:'+ x , function(data, status){

   if(data=='true'){
     alert('email exists');
   }
   if(data=='false'){

     alert('email does not exist');
   }
 });

}
```

Comment: You do not return anything from the middleware? Maybe you want `res.send("true");` or something like that?

Comment: Can you show your model once

Comment: Is that an express `router` object?

Comment: @JonasWilms there is no middleware in this example, its an endpoint.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is in the route that you should not use `:` in client-side, that should be

```
'/users/checkUserInDatabase/'+ x
```

and server side should be

```
'/checkUserInDatabase/:email'
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to `res.send(JSON.stringify(user));` right after your console.log.

Comment: I think the problem is that the output of `console.log(user);` is null, not that the route doesn't return a response. But yeah, it was missing that.

Comment: yeah, then it would be an issue with your model or request to the model is invalid.

Comment: Im not the OP, but yes, precisely